# Order of image preprocessing steps

Tags: image, image-processing

I have a set of color images and I want to do the following:

- Convert to grayscale
- Make them all some uniform size
- Histogram equalize each

My question is, will the order of these 3 operations have a significant impact on the final image?

Comment: I think Equalisation after GrayscaleConversion
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization#Histogram_equalization_of_color_images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conversion to gray scale, causes some data loss. For example you may have a very narrow red histogram which can be equalized very well, but when the picture is converted to gray scale, the narrow red histogram gets mixed with blue and green (assuming RGB) and you lose the particular information you had about each color's histogram. I think doing histogram equalize on each color (r,g,b) before conversion to gray scale makes more sense. the drawback is doing equalize histogram 3 times. Re-sizing the picture does not seem to affect the result.

Comment: So perhaps resize it (which will usually result in a smaller image) first to slightly speed up other computations?